# Uploadify using multiple files, one mvc controller call

Tags: uploadify

From all I have read in Stackoverflow and Google, it seems that once again I am forced to work around IE. Since it doesn't support multi, I am forced to use Uploadify or some other 3rd party pluggin. Thanks Microsoft..
I want to verify that there is no way to automatically batch multi-select files into one MVC controller call using Uploadify. I think there are ways whereby a user can add files, then press a button to upload the files, but is this it??? What pluggin will allow a user to select 4 files, close the file browse dialog, then automatically send all of the files in one http post?????
thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can check the documentation of [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation), it can select multiple files using `multi` option.

You can also upload after all the files are queued using auto:false option.

Here is what you can [upload](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/upload/) after queuing