# how to use uploadify to post IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> object to an actionresult in my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am using uploadify plugin to select multiple files in IE. I am able to postback one file at a time currently as HttpPostedFileBase object. If I am selecting 3 files in file upload dialog, I am posting 3 times once for each file. Is there a way to postback all three files at a time and extract them as IEnumerable object?

My requirement is, I would need the filename and fileContent for all files, pass them to a  model and call a service with this model object as parameter.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a way of getting all the files in my .js file itself and then do an explicit post with all those files? The queue would have the list of files that are to be uploaded, if I set auto: false, all the files would be stored in queue object. I could then post all of them at a time using uploadify.. Can i do this?

Comment: I tried the reply in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765994/uploadify-using-multiple-files-one-mvc-controller-call?rq=1 but where do I invoke the call to uploadify('upload','*')? I tried it on OnQueueComplete but it doesnt seem to work